# Jenkins pipeline from job DSL not matching branches is fixed when re-saving without modification. Why?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am using job DSL plugin to create a jenkins multibranch pipeline job.

The generated job will not match any branches of my git repo:

```
Checking branches...
  Checking branch feature/xyz
    Does not meet criteria
  Checking branch main
    Does not meet criteria
  Checking branch release/1.0.0
    Does not meet criteria
```

When I open the configuration of the generated job and then click "save" (without making any changes) the repo is scanned again and this time the branches will match:

```
Checking branches...
  Checking branch feature/xyz
    Met criteria
  Checking branch main
    Met criteria
  Checking branch release/1.0.0
    Met criteria
```

When I look at the *config.xml* file for the original vs "saved" job the difference appears to be the following:

Original *config.xml* (via job dsl)

```
<sources class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList">
```

Updated *config.xml* (after saving unmodified configuration)

```
<sources class="jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchSourceList" plugin="branch-api@2.1122.v09cb_8ea_8a_724">
```

That is, the *config.xml* originally created via job DSL plugin did not have a 'plugin' attribute, but "saving" an unmodified config is re-written by jenkins and a 'plugin' attribute is added.

I'm not sure why re-writing the job config (without any actual changes) would fix a branch scanning issue. Is there a plugin issue here? Do I need to tweak my job DSL to specify a particular plugin? And if so, how?

Using:

- Jenkins 2.422
- Jenkins Job DSL plugin 1.84
- Jenkins Branch API plugin 2.1122.v09cb_8ea_8a_724

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The DSL included the following:

```
factory {
  remoteJenkinsFileWorkflowBranchProjectFactory {
    remoteJenkinsFileSCM {
      gitSCM  { ...
```

I had not specified a path to the Jenkinsfile for this remote SCM, as the documentation mentioned the following:

*Relative location within the checkout of your Pipeline script. Note that it will always be run inside a Groovy sandbox. Default is Jenkinsfile if left empty.*

That bit about the default value was not correct. I had to manually specify the path, even though I was using the default value:

```
factory {
  remoteJenkinsFileWorkflowBranchProjectFactory {
    remoteJenkinsFile 'Jenkinsfile'
    remoteJenkinsFileSCM {
      gitSCM  { ...
```

Now the generated job from the DSL will recognize branches. Huzzah!